# Calling next Function: Python

Tags: python, function

I have this function:

```
def abandoned_station():
print """
.....
""" 

    next = raw_input(prompt)

    if next == "store room" or "Store Room" or "Store room":
        store_room()
    elif next == "control room" or "Control Room" or "Control room":
        control_room()
    elif next == "Look" or "look":
        abandoned_station
    else:
        print "Sorry, I do not understand that command."
```

But when I input 'Control Room' at the prompt, it goes to the store_room function. If I enter anything else, it goes back to the original abandoned_station function - it doesn't even say it doesn't understand.

Have I created a loop here that I have missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use `next` as a variable name, `next` is a `builtin_function` in python.

Comment: What should I use as my variable name then?

Comment: anything that does not shadow a python builtin or type maybe something like `user_input`. You can use `if user_input.lower() ==  "store room"` instead of using all the `or` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do your comparisons like that:

```
if next == "store room" or "Store Room" or "Store room":
```

What it really means is

```
if (next == "store room") or ("Store Room") or ("Store room"):
```

That means, Pythons dynamic nature evaluates the boolean of a string, which is True unless it is empty. You have to compare every clause with next:

```
if (next == "store room") or (next  == "Store Room") or (next == "Store room"):
```

To quote the Python documentation:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are
>   used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted
>   as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings
>   and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets
>   and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. (See the
>   **nonzero**() special method for a way to change this.)

Source: [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Comment: Also, OP needs to actually *call* `abandoned_station` for the `look` command.